# What does Nginx take into account when caching a request?

Tags: nginx, caching, nginx-cache

What attributes(headers, cookies) besides url does Nginx take into account when caching a request?

I was trying to find out this information in *nginx/log/access.log* file. I have found only information about what type of request had been made(GET) and its status(404, 200, etc.).

Here my *nginx.conf* file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid logs/nginx.pid;
    
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# MY TEST SERVER
http {
    # CACHE
    proxy_cache_path "C:\data\cache" levels=1:2 keys_zone=all:32m;

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;
            proxy_cache all;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 502 503 1s;
            proxy_cache_valid any 10s;
        }
      
    server {
        listen 81;
        location / {
            root "C:\data\www";
        }
        location /images/ {
            root "C:\data";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What does Nginx take into account when caching a request?

The full URL

The relevant config for what Nginx uses when caching a request is [proxy_cache_key](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key)

> Syntax:   proxy_cache_key string;
>
> Default:   proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
>
> Context:  http, server, location
>
> Defines a key for caching, for example
>
> ```
> proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
> ```
>
> By default, the
> directive’s value is close to the string
>
> ```
> proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args;
> ```

So by default Nginx does not take into account any headers when caching a request, only the full url (with get Args)

### How to customize the cache key

To customize the cache key only requires using the `proxy_cache_key` directive.

To cache based on a cookie value, there's already an example in the documentation - but I suggest:

```
proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri:u:$cookie_user";
```

Why add more text to the key? Consider what happens if you use multiple cookies like so:

```
proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri:u:$cookie_user:g:$cookie_group";
```

It avoids the possibility of a request with only `$cookie_group` colliding with the cached content for something with the same value only in `$cookie_user`. It also makes it easier to understand what the files on disk contain, if you have the need to look.

If you want to use an arbitrary header - just include [the variable for that header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) e.g.:

```
proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri:n:$http_name";
```